# Is it possible to make a group of classes that are similar?

Tags: c#

I am wondering if I can make a group of classes that all have the same functions, but the algorithm in each is different. Let's say we had. Multiply.cs, Add.cs ,and Subtract.cs. Each would have this structure:

```
public Class(int BaseInt)
{
    ...
}

public MakeNumber(int Oint)
{
    ...
}
```

So the Multiply.cs MakeNumber() would be different from the Add.cs MakeNumber() method, but both would return an int and so could be used in similar contexts. Is there any way to pair these classes up, let's say we call this group operators. Would I be able to declare a variable under this group.

```
Operators MyOperator = new Operators();
```

But then later I could say

```
MyOperator = Multiply;
```

Comment: Go read up on [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) :)

Comment: Either you use interfaces where each class implements its own routine inside each method. But this smells like less knowledge of oop designs. In your case i tend to inherit . Design your model in order to override base class methods properly.

Comment: Totally possible, you use inheritance and polymorphism. So we don't have to write a dissertation on OOP, could you narrow the question a bit?

Answer (score 1):

That sort of thing is a common design pattern for use with interfaces. Using your example would however be a bit weird.

```
public interface IMakesNumber
{
public int MakeNumber(int number);
}
```

Then all your classes can implement it...

```
public MyMultiplication : IMakesNumber
{
public int MakeNumber(int number)
{
//bla
}
}
```

Then you could do something like this

```
IMakesNumber myOperator = //Generally you'd use a Factory Design Pattern

int something = myOperator.MakeNumber(no);
```

Depending on the actual type of myOperator - whatever you implemented will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider an [Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)<sup>1</sup> (note this is *not* "making numbers" as the original, but such could be done using the same ideas; this just seems like the more logical goal)

```
interface IBinaryOp { int Apply(int a, int b); }
```

then different implementations can be created

```
class Add : IBinaryOp {
    public int Apply(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}

class Multiply : IBinaryOp {
    public int Apply(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
}
```

and then the resulting instances can be used [polymorphically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)

```
IBinaryOp op = (new Random().NextDouble() < .5) ? new Add() : new Multiply();
int r = op.Apply(2, 4);
// r is 6 or 8, depending upon which instance was created
```

---

<sup>1</sup> While C# also allows inclusion polymorphism through [derived classes and inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx), I tend to avoid this and use interfaces - even in situations where I use inheritance to help with shared implementation - for exposed types.